# TFS REST API System.IterationPath returns error

Tags: python-3.x, tfs, azure-devops, python-requests, azure-devops-rest-api

I am passing the Iteration path to the field in REST API Query using python requests library.

```
>>> payload = {"name": "Audit Work Items","wiql": ("SELECT [System.Id],[System.WorkItemType],[System.Title],[System.AssignedTo],[System.State],[System.Tags],[System.IterationPath] FROM workitems WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' OR [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [System.IterationPath] = '\2CES\Backlog\2020\20.1\20.1.5' ORDER BY [System.Id]")}
>>> response  = requests.post(organization_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False, json=payload)
>>> response.text
'{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF51011: The specified iteration path does not exist. The error is caused by «\'\\u0002CES\\\\Backlog\x820\\u0010.1\\u0010.1.5\'».","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Wiql.SyntaxException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage","typeKey":"SyntaxException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}'
>>>
```

I am unable to understand the innerException returned by the REST API and why is the path showing some binary characters in the error message ?

Can anyone please help me fix this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try escaping the backslash character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes need to be escaped. `\2CES` is being interpreted as a Unicode character. Try `\\2CES`

Comment: The solution worked. I took an ID for a work item and executed it through requests GET call from python interpreter which returned the result set as dictionary. I found the System.IterationPath has been escaped with back slash in the response output.